# Can we pass value to annotations at runtime?

Tags: java, annotations, date-format

We need to create an annotation in java called DateFormat. It will take string dateformat eg.

```
class  User
{
    @Dateformat("MMM/dd/yyyy")
    private Date birthDate;
}
```

Here the date format is statically passed as an argument to the annotation. Is there any way we can pass this date format at run time  may be from session.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly, no.

But if you have a property-resolution mechanism, you can have something like:

```
@DateFormat("${birth.date.format}")
```

And resolve the `birth.date.format` property when parsing the annotation.

Comment: We will have this date format in the database. Which we will fetch once user logins to the application. Date format is not stored in the properties file. Its stored in the user preference table in the database.

Comment: well, then make your annotation parser load the configuration from the user

Comment: It all depends on how you parse your annotation. How do you parse it, and where?

Answer (score 1):

The Java Language Spec dictates that an annotation parameter value must be a constant expression. From [section 9.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#255114):

> An element type T is commensurate with an element value V if and only
>   if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - T is an array type E[] and either:
>
>   - V is an ElementValueArrayInitializer and each ElementValueInitializer (analogous to a variable initializer in an
>       array initializer) in V is commensurate with E. Or
>   - V is an ElementValue that is commensurate with T.
> - The type of V is assignment compatible (§5.2) with T and, furthermore:
>
>   - If T is a primitive type or String, V is a constant expression ([§15.28](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5313)).
>   - V is not null.
>   - if T is Class, or an invocation of Class, and V is a class literal (§15.8.2).
>   - If T is an enum type, and V is an enum constant.

The key item in this case is the first sub-point of the second block.

Answer (score 0):

No. What you could do is have an annotation like

```
@DateFormat(sessionKey = "foo")
```

The tool/api which uses the annotation would extract the value of the sessionKey attribute, and get the pattern to apply from the session, using given session attribute key.